# executing multiple commands by taking user input windows terminal

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to run a bat file, in which I have two commands to execute sequentially.

```
@echo off
::taking version no. as input
set /p productVersion="Enter new product version: "
::executing first command
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=%productVersion% && set /p commitChanges="new version is set for all modules %productVersion% Do you want commit your changes for all pom files :(y/n)" && call:commitChanges %commitChanges%
EXIT /B
::executing second command, after taking input y/n
:commitChanges
If %~1=="y" goto yes
If %~1=="n" goto no
If %~1=="Y" goto yes
If %~1=="N" goto no
EXIT /B
:no
mvn versions:revert
EXIT /B
:yes
mvn versions:commit
EXIT /B
```

first command executes successfully and line taking input for second command comes,but terminal gets closed and second command is not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be better off using an else clause:

```dos
@Echo Off
:AskFirst
Set/P "productVersion=Enter new product version: "
If "%productVersion%"=="" GoTo AskFirst
Call mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=%productVersion%
Echo=new version is set for all modules %productVersion%
:AskSecond
Set/P "commitChanges=Do you want commit your changes for all pom files :(y/n) "
If /I "%commitChanges%"=="y" (Call mvn versions:commit) Else (
   If /I "%commitChanges%"=="n" (Call mvn versions:revert) Else (
      GoTo AskSecond))
Echo=changes have been committed
Pause
Exit/B
```

Answer (score 0):

An `EXIT /B` instruction exits from the current routine, hence the routine will be exited once `mvn versions:set -Dne...` has ended.

Comment: even if I remove all  EXIT /B , it is still not working

Comment: What is `mvn`? If `mvn` is a batch file (`mvn.bat`) then you need `call mvn` in order to have batch return to the procedure after completing `mvn`.

Comment: I removed EXIT /B and applied call before mvn command. first command executed and second input statement prompted but after entering a key, it showed an error : goto was unexpected at this time.

Comment: `%~1` refers to the first parameter provided to the batch file. You need (eg) `if "%commitChanges%"=="y" ....` note that `if /i...` will perform a case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: @echo off
set /p productVersion="Enter new product version: "
call mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=%productVersion% && set /p commitChanges="new version is set for all modules %productVersion% Do you want commit your changes for all pom files :(y/n)" && call:commitChanges %commitChanges%
:commitChanges
If "%commitChanges%"=="y" ( mvn versions:commit )
IF "%commitChanges%"=="n" ( mvn versions:revert )
IF "%commitChanges%"=="Y" ( mvn versions:commit )
IF "%commitChanges%"=="N" ( mvn versions:revert )

Comment: Above program working fine, but if condition is executing twice.

Comment: You need an `exit /b` or `goto :eof` (colon **required**) before the label `:commitchanges`. Batch simply executes line-by-line. When `call mvn...` terminates, having `call`ed `commitchanges` once, it simply continues to the next line - which is the `if` statement group.